# What is the chronological timeline from Yuuki's birth to when Kaname saves her from a vampire in the snow?

Tags: vampire-knight

The *Vampire Knight* timeline is kind of confusing and a lot of the backstory is told in relatively fragmented pieces.

What is the chronological timeline from Yuuki's birth to when Kaname saves her from a vampire in the snow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer includes the information from the manga. The anime makes a reference to a couple of key elements which don't get revealed until the 2nd half of the manga which occurs 1 year after the first half (what the anime covers).

Below is the list of events in chronological order from Kaname's birth to Yuuki's "awakening" as a human:

(Note: The **[M]** indicates information found in the 13th volume of *Vampire Knight*. In the anime, Juri makes a reference to Rido killing Kaname and awakening Lord Kaname)

- Kaname is born in secret
- Rido takes him to the coffin beneath the Kuran Estate **[M]**
- Rido sacrifices Kaname to awaken Lord Kaname in hopes to absorb Lord Kaname **[M]**
- Lord Kaname wounds Rido (As Rido woke him up, Rido is Lord Kaname's master and cannot be killed) **[M]**
- Having been woken in an incomplete state, Lord Kaname reverts into an infant to stop the thousands of years worth of hunger which would be sated by him slaughtering the Kuran Family, represses memories so they won't get in the way **[M]**
- Haruka finds Kaname's sheet bloodied, finds Lord Kaname as an infant **[M]**
- Juri finds Haruka, and both take Lord Kaname and raise him as they would have with Kaname **[M]**
- Yuuki is born in secret
- Kaname begins to go outside, finds the rose that only blooms every 10 years, returns to tell Yuuki the next time he sees it he'll encase it in resin for her
- Rido learns of Yuuki, finds Kuran Residence, accompanied by Vampires from the Senate
- Haruka faces Rido, is killed
- Juri sacrifices life to turn Yuuki into a human
- Kaname faces Rido, mortally wounds Rido but is unable to kill as he is Lord Kaname and Rido was the one who woke him
- Kaname escapes with Yuuki (asleep?) to find Cross
- Kaname leaves Yuuki in snow to deal with Perusing Vampires **[M]**
- Yuuki awakes, Vampires find Yuuki, Kaname returns and protects Yuuki

In the anime, the fight against Rido at Cross Academy plays out differently, and in the manga, Kaname gathers the Elder Council (The Senate) and kills them before going to attempt to kill Takuma's Father, so if a third season (or second if you think *Guilty* is still the first season) of the anime comes, it may have differences when it reveals this part.

Comment: Do you mean Rido? Because there is no character named "Freedo".

Comment: @kuwaly yep, i keep hearing Freedo but Rido sounds more right, changed it to Rido, it's for that very reason i don't name Kaname's mother cause i hear Jurry

Comment: Kaname/Yuuki's mother is named Juri. Their father is Haruka.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just Yuuki born, gets hidden away, evil uncle goes after her, parents get killed, kaname takes her to cross, yuuki gets attacked, and kaname saves her?

Comment: should point out that Freedo was after them even before Yuuki was born at least in the anime has when he arrived Kaname's mother does say that Freedo killed their first son, still trying to compile the storyline myself